# extract information from website using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the iformations about the indicator facts in this website https://otx.alienvault.com/indicator/ip/13.107.21.200 using this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
theurl = "https://otx.alienvault.com/indicator/ip/13.107.21.200"
thepage = urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
print(soup.find('div',{"class":"item-container"}))
```

but i got **None** as result instead of a list of existing facts in the website !
any idea about what is wrong on my code

Comment: Does this element with class "item-container" exist on the page?

Comment: The site uses javascript to populate the webpage. BeatifulSoup only works for static html. Switch to selenium or similar *or* reverse engineer the api the page uses and call the backend yourself that provides the data you want to extract fromm the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the necessary information from the site using the API

```
import requests


def get_facts(ip):
    response = requests.get(f'https://otx.alienvault.com/otxapi/indicators/ip/analysis/{ip}')
    print(response.json()['facts'])


get_facts('13.107.21.200')
```